# JavaScript equivalent of PHP passing parameter

Tags: javascript

In PHP, I've used this:

```
do_it( $var2 = 'something_cool' );

function do_it( $var1, $var2 ) {
// does something
}
```

In JavaScript, I'm not quite sure the notation.

```
do_it( var2 = 'something_cool' ); // This isn't right, I don't think.

function do_it( var1, var2 ) {
// does something
}
```

I want to define var2 but leave var1 empty. What should my do_it look like for the line in question?

Comment: It's "wrong" in php either: This will assign `'something_cool'` to `$var1` within the function and not (what you probably expect) to `$var2`. I don't know, where you get this from, but there are no named parameters in PHP....

Comment: I swear I've done that in PHP... ok I was probably working with WordPress where it sets default values for parameters, and I was only changing one of them. Hence why I thought I could do that same in JavaScript. D'oh!

Comment: But (as mentioned) you can only set parameters from left to right .... There are no named parameters in PHP!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of the two are correct. In PHP `var1` will get that value in the function. In JS, if you don't want to assign something to the first parameter, make it `null`.

```
do_it(null, 'something_cool');
```

And then inside the function, check if it's null and perhaps give it a default value if it is. Or just reorder them so you don't have to. In JS you can pass any number of parameters into a function.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP version will print a missing second argument error.
For optional variables in Javascript:

```
function A(var1, var2)
{
     if (!var2)
          var2 = "default";
}

A(1);
```

Comment: No it won't. It'll only trigger a PHP warning unless you have a custom error handler set to throw an ErrorException.

Comment: Yep my bad. My overall saying is that his PHP is wrong, and it will print some error.